# Convert a multiple aggregation Elasticsearch query to NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Can someone please help me convert this ES query to NEST / C#?

```
GET /listings/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "suburb_5715329": {
      "filter":
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": 
          [
            {
              "range": 
              {
                "price": 
                {
                  "gt": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": 
              {
                "location.hrefs": ["/locations/5715329"]
              }
            },
            {
              "term": 
              {
                "searchType": 
                {
                  "value": "Buy"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": 
          [
            {
              "term": 
              {
                "isExclusiveList": 
                {
                  "value": true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "median": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "price",
            "percents": [
              50
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "suburb_5716208": {
      "filter":
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": 
          [
            {
              "range": 
              {
                "price": 
                {
                  "gt": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": 
              {
                "location.hrefs": ["/locations/5716208"]
              }
            },
            {
              "term": 
              {
                "searchType": 
                {
                  "value": "Buy"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": 
          [
            {
              "term": 
              {
                "isExclusiveList": 
                {
                  "value": true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "median": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "price",
            "percents": [
              50
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially i have a list of location hrefs, and i want to calculate the median of each. In this case i am hardcoding the aggregation (e.g `suburb_NN`), but i need to build that up dynamically, which im struggling with.

Any help would be great :)

Thanks

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: @imotov version 7.2.0

Comment: Just checking since, the client got changed quite a bit between 7.x and 8.x. By the way 7.2.0 is no longer maintained nor supported. The NEST client that you need to use with 7.x has really extensive documentation with plenty of examples, including how to translate DSL from JSON to NEST in case of aggregations - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/writing-aggregations.html Do you have some particular issues?

Comment: @imotov i've done basic aggregations before, but never this way where it's a dynamic set of inputs, and i want to do one aggregation _per_ of those inputs, in one call. im kinda scratching my head on where to start..

Comment: Did you try using overload of `Aggregations` method on the client which is accepting `AggregationDictionary` and build dictionary dynamically based on the input? Something like `elasticClient.SearchAsync<object>(searchDescriptor => { var aggregationDictionary = new AggregationDictionary("", new AggregationContainerDescriptor<object>().Terms()); return searchDescriptor.Aggregations(aggregationDictionary); });`.

Comment: @Rob yep, was on that track but just couldnt get the syntax right. If you have an example that works, can you pls put it up as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AggregationDictionary` to build dynamically aggregations based on the input and pass it directly to `Aggregations` when calling `SearchAsync` like this.

Here is simple example

```
var aggregationDictionary = new AggregationDictionary();
var aggregationContainer = new FilterAggregation("filter");
aggregationContainer.Filter = new QueryContainer(new BoolQuery { Must = new QueryContainer[] { new MatchAllQuery() } });
aggregationContainer.Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary(new Dictionary<string, AggregationContainer>
    { { "median", new PercentilesAggregation("median", "price") { Percents = new double[] { 50 } } } });
aggregationDictionary.Add("suburb_5715329", aggregationContainer);

var searchAsync = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<object>(searchDescriptor => searchDescriptor.Aggregations(aggregationDictionary));
```

Which will produce following query into Elasticsearch

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "suburb_5715329": {
            "aggs": {
                "median": {
                    "percentiles": {
                        "field": "price",
                        "percents": [50.0]
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                            "match_all": {}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm quite sure it can be simplified by building `QueryContainer` instance with fluent interface but forgot and can't google it so far.